# Two blocks: one with dynamic width, one with the same width of the dynamic one

Tags: html, css

I basically have a container with inside two blocks: one block will have a dynamic width (based on the text within it) and the other one should be the same width of the dynamic width. If the second block has a major width since the text inside, it have to break the text in order to keep the same width of the first block.

```
<container>
  <fixed_dynamic>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </fixed_dynamic>
  <samedynamic>
    few words
  </samedynamic>
</container>
```

I could achieve something doing in this manner: https://jsfiddle.net/prxus5vm

The problem is that if I try to write something in the second width that make the div stretch, it will not break the words: https://jsfiddle.net/prxus5vm/1/. It should break the words and keep the width of the first block.

Any solution? I'm searching for a CSS solution, want to avoid to use javascript if possible.

Comment: If you use the table-layout, you might use width and white-space to shrink it as much as possible. then the second div will need to be an inline-box to 100% width avalaible : https://jsfiddle.net/u3t6faw9/ You may also add afew extra bits of text https://jsfiddle.net/nexbfc5u/ a couple side by side https://jsfiddle.net/430saypj/

Comment: @G-Cyr That's great, thanks! If you want to insert it as answer, I will surely accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use the `table-layout` properties to shrink down a parent as much as possible,you are missing  a small `width` being set.

Once you have this done, the first element can be a block of text or an image. Finally `white-space:nowrap` comes handy to avoid text to wrap and set the width you are looking for.

```css
div {
  display: inline-table;/*NEEDED          inline for demo it is still using the table-layout */
  width: 1%;            /*NEDEED          or 0 , see it alike a min-width */
  margin:5px                          /* not needed here */
}

div * {
  padding: 0.25em ;                    /* not needed here */
  margin: 0;                           /* not needed here */
}

div h1 {
  background: green;                   /* not needed here */
  white-space: nowrap;  /* NEDEED */
  font-size:1.1rem                     /* not needed here */
}

p {

  background: yellow;                  /* not needed here */

}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </h1>
  <p>
    more words than fixed dynamic block 
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>
    A shorter text 
  </h1>
  <p>
    more words than fixed from dynamic block
  </p>
  <p>
    and a few more words
  </p>
</div>

<h1>BUT, there is a disclaimer !</h1>
<div>
  <h1>
    short
  </h1>
  <p>
    here are words that are themselves longer than the reference ....
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `width: fit-content;` to fixed width container, now the width will be equal to content width, and added script that take the width of the first container and assign it to your dynamic container

```js
var fixed_width = $("fixed_dynamic").css("width");
$("samedynamic").css("width", fixed_width);
console.log(fixed_width)
```

```css
container {
  display: table;
}

fixed_dynamic {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  background: green;
}

samedynamic {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<container>
  <fixed_dynamic>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </fixed_dynamic>
  <samedynamic>
    more words than fixed dynamic block
  </samedynamic>
</container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I had already thought of it, but as I said, I would prefer to not use javascript for something like that. @G-Cyr offered a pure CSS solution that I will use.